# "User control" with MVC PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I was wondering how to achieve an asp.net "user control" like functionality with PHP in a MVC framework, specifically CodeIgniter.

To explain better what I want, here's some guidance:

- A .net user control is a file, with both aspx and code (c#/vb) that provides a functionality across every page that implement it (say, a shopping cart). It is easily added to a Master Page which is a container for every other pages in the site.
- In MVC structure, a page is loaded by the controller, which loads the View. I understand I can load Views inside Views, but how to provide the controller code for "cross site views" without repeating it every main controller?

Example: I have a view that loads Categories from database into a select list and this view is on top of every page. As I shouldn't (and I'm not sure if it is even possible) access my Category model from the view, where do I put the code to load this data without having to repeat it in every function in every controller?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid duplicating code in each controller, then simply extend the `CI_Controller` class and do all of the setup in your new Controller class upon instantiation ... and have all of your normal controllers inherit from `New_Controller`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've been doing it like that, but didn't seem the right way. I'll end up with a huge New_Controller file, with code from everywhere all mixed up and being inherited from every other controller class. Seems really clumsy.

Comment: @nosuchnick - There's no rule which says you should only have *one* such controller -- you could have one `Base_Controller` that contains some common code, and then a `Shopping_Controller` that specializes with common Shopping Cart functions and data, and another `Shopping_Specials_Controller` that adds in some specialized functionality ... and all of this is separate from the `Admin_Controller` (which also inherits from `Base_Controller`) -- so you are only loading what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As Sean said, if the functionality is at Controller level you should extend CI_Controller. 
May be some functionality should be at view level, so a loader view can be used to help you keep the global layout of every page and include the common features. that's something like:

[view] layout.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es" lang="es">
<head>
        <?php
            $this->load->view('meta', $data);
        ?>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">

            <?php
            $this->load->view('header', $data);
            ?>
            <div id="contents">

                <?php include ('menu_izq.php'); ?>

                <div id="page">
                    <?php $this->load->view($page, $data); ?>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            <?php $this->load->view('footer');?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In your controller you should always load this view and pass in the parameter array the value of the contents real view, like in

```
    $data['page'] = 'incidents'; // this is the real contents
    $stylesheets[] = '/scripts/jscalendar-1.0/skins/aqua/theme.css';
    $data['stylesheets'] = $stylesheets;
    $scripts[] = '/scripts/jscalendar-1.0/calendar.js';
    $scripts[] = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js';
    $scripts[] = '/scripts/autoNumeric-1.4.1.js';
    $scripts[] = '/scripts/autoLoader.js';
    $data['scripts'] = $scripts;
    $this->load->view('container',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked very little with master pages, mainly in Sharepoint but if you want a `front.master` page so to speak and then load all other pages within that context your best bet would be to create a new library as your view handler and pro grammatically design it to load the secondary view within the master.

A simple class consisting of:

```
class MasterViewTemplate
{
    public $master = "v1.php";
    private $data = array();

    public function __set($key,$value)
    {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($key)
    {
        return $this->data[$key];
    }

    public function setMaster($master)
    {
        $this->master = $master;
    }

    public function display($page)
    {
        //Load the master file
        //Load the inner $page file
        //Inject the page contents into the master
    }
}
```

IS this the kind of thing you was looking for.

Comment: It was not. But now that we're at it, why does set and get functions have __ before their names?

Comment: there special functions, the `__get` allows you to do `$this->something` passing the `something` in as the parameter. and the set allows you to `$this->something = 'value'` http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: Ah ok, like the get/set methods on .net properties. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my own question: i found something worth checking. it provides Multiple MVC triads: https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home